# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Task Outcome Approve / Reject Buttons no longer display

Tags: workflow, workflow-tasks-list

I created a simply custom workflow that up until recently had the approve and reject buttons on edit task form.  Now I have a approve or reject drop down.  How do I get the buttons back?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, Your task is created of "**Task**" content type.

You will need to add "**Workflow Task(2013)**" content type in your task list and then create task of "Workflow Task(2013)" content type.

So it will automatically give you Approve- Reject buttons.

Please refer this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209530/approval-workflow-for-task-list-is-not-working/209532?noredirect=1#comment223959_209532).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that following features are not deactivated by mistake:

1. Site collection features > SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
2. Manage Site Collection features > Publishing Approval workflow feature

Answer (score 0):

You should have Task outcome as the last column in the column order to get the outcome as buttons

To do that, you need to goto

> List settings-> click on the content type name(workflow task 2013) ->
>   click on column order -> Make the task outcome as last column and
>   click ok

[image]

Now if you refresh your task edit page, you should be able to see the Approve/Reject as buttons

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having the 'Task Outcome' as the last column in the Content Type, you will have to ensure 'Task Status', '% Complete' and 'Priority' are not hidden.