# Approval workflow for Task List is not working

Tags: 2013, workflow, task-list, approval-process

It's almost 10 pm and I've been at this for about 12 hours already.  So I am now throwing in the towel and asking for assistance, please.

I am using SP Designer 2013.  I created a simple "Allegedly" vacation workflow. Basically, User goes to the form where they enter time Off.

After they hit Save, the email does come through to the assigned Supervisor for Approval.

The Link is provided to the task and the Supervisor is taken to the task

After the edit button is selected, the supervisor is taken to this screen:
[image]

I have tried multiple ways to get that Approve and Rejected Buttons on the page at the bottom with Save and Cancel button with No Success.

The Task Status is changed to Completed, % Complete is changed to 100, and Task Outcome is changed to Approved.  When I save the task, Nothing happens. I am taken to a list that shows the work flows that have been completed. I go back to my leave Requests

They all say pending approval, so I am thinking that means it is stuck on that portion of the workflow?
Here is my documentation:
[image]

Please... Help... I can send more screen shots if needed.

Thanks!
-Almarosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, Your task is created of "**Task**" content type.

You will need to add "**Workflow Task(2013)**" content type in your task list and then create task of "**Workflow Task(2013)**" content type.

So it will automatically give you Approve- Reject buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried what you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm wondering if something is wrong with the default workflow 2013 content type. I've tried everything from rebuilding the list and rebuilding the workflow. If I try to create the workflow through the website and not the designer, it will work. But then I can't edit that workflow back in the designer to make it do what I want. Does that make sense ?

Comment: It is not best approach to edit SharePoint OOTB workflow.Please add content type column in view and check for which content type your task is create or remove all content type and use only Workflow task (2013) and check.