# Approved/Rejected Buttons Missing From SharePoint Task Approval Screen

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I was adding in a task field in effort to try and import data from a list, when somehow something was changed to where the approved/rejected button disappeared. I removed the fields I added but the buttons are still missing. I know that I should not use the OOTB SharePoint 2013 Task (I am trying to create a custom one to get away from this) but this is the way it was created and I am stuck frantically looking to solve this mess.

I have followed other posts but nothing has worked so far. [Related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209530/approval-workflow-for-task-list-is-not-working/209532?noredirect=1#comment223959_209532)

[image: approve/reject]

Answer (score 3):

Found the root cause of this via a post [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b68b3b6a-5919-4ac1-8831-0ddfedd0730d/workflow-approvalreject-buttons-have-dissapeared?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Basically, you need to make sure "Task Outcome" is the last item in the column order. Once it is the last item, the approved/rejected buttons will appear. 
[image: Column order]

Answer (score 2):

It is maybe also worthy to add that it is not just about making "Task Outcome" as a last column but also "Task Status" and "% Complete" should be **not hidden**.

So obvious SharePoint, so obvious.